# What is the non-deprecated version of pandas_datareader?

Tags: python, pandas, deprecated

I'm currently getting back into python and working on some light data analytics. I was using pandas_datareader to pull data but I'm this warning

```
FutureWarning: pandas.util.testing is deprecated. Use the functions in the public API at pandas.testing instead.
from pandas.util.testing import assert_frame_equal
```

Is there a new version I missed or is this warning something I should simply ignore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, pandas current version is `1.0.3`, Second, `pandas.util` top-level module is private so it is not guaranteed to be stable, please check the [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/index.html) for more information.

And third, [assert_frame_equal](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal.html?highlight=assert_frame_equal) now available as part of `pandas.testing`

Comment: Thank you kind sir!